# Maximum height of a quad tree

Tags: trees

If we have a quad tree where each node must have 0 or 4 children, is there an expression that can me the maximum height of a quad tree with $n$ nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tree of height $m$ where at each level only one node has children will have $1+4(m-1)$ nodes, assuming a tree with only one node has height one.  The height will be $m=\frac{n+3}{4}$ for $n$ nodes.  If your number of nodes is not $1 \pmod 4$, it won't work as each branch adds 4 nodes.

Comment: I think you've used $n$ for both the height and the number of nodes.

Comment: @joriki:  You are right.  Fixed.  Thanks.